# Destroying the content of a leaflet popup when the popup is closed

Tags: leaflet

I've got a map that has some marker. When an user clicks on a marker, a mini detail popup is shown. What I need is to completely destroy the popup when it's closed, so next time an user re-open it it's created from scratch again.

here's the code I use to show the popup:

```
private addMarker(mainPost: MainPost) {
    const marker = L.circleMarker([mainPost.latitude, mainPost.longitude], {
      icon: svgIcon,
      title: mainPost.position
    });

    marker.on('click', (event) => {

      this.apiService.getMainPostDetails(mainPost.id).subscribe(result => {

        if (result.didError) {
          //TODO : add toastr
          return;
        }
        if (this.currentSelectedMarker != null) {
        }
        var component = this.createCustomPopup(result.model);
        //alert('componente creato');
        marker.bindPopup(component, {
          maxWidth: "auto",
          maxHeigth: "auto"
        });

        marker.openPopup();
      });

    });

    marker.mainPost = mainPost;
    marker.addTo(this.map);

    this.markers.push(marker);

  }

private createCustomPopup(mainPost: MainPost) {

    //const divContainer = this.renderer.createElement('div');

    const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(LeaftletPopupDetailComponent);

    //Set the component inputs manually 
    component.instance.mainPost = mainPost;

    //Manually invoke change detection, automatic wont work, but this is Ok if the component doesn't change
    component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    return component.location.nativeElement;
  }
```

I need to open in this way so the data related to the popup are correctly loaded only when needed.

I've realized that the content is re-used since the second time I open the popup I got a leaflet error (in the detail there's another mini map showing the point on a mini map) and it tells the map has already initialized.

BTW I need to destroy the component, so I ensure it's recreated from zero.

Comment: If the error message is about the map already being initialized, it means that you're calling `L.map()` (or `new L.Map()`) twice. Debug that. Your problem is not about the popups.

Comment: @IvanSanchez this is referred to the mini map show in the popup... I know this, that's why I need to destroy the popup. I've the main leaflet map, then when a user clicks on the marker, it shows a detail with another leaflet mini map

Comment: OK, so there's a leaflet map in the popup. Show us the code where that map is being created.